# How to insert single quotes on a databound asp:hyperlink field in asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am trying to bind an ASP.NET hyperlink to the "Handle" column of my dataset like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="idTracking" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:SendPath(" + Eval( "Handle", "{0}") + ")" %>' Text="Test" />                                            
</ItemTemplate>
```

I would like the NavigateUrl to read:

```
javascript:SendPath('123abc')
```

However, I cannot introduce the single quotes.  How do I do this?

Comment: @unkown (yahoo): I tweaked the title a bit.  It was "How to I insert..."

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the text property of the hyperlink control automatically encodes, I've always has to simply do it as a standard html anchor tag.

So something like this.

```
<a href='<%# "javascript:SendPath(" + Eval( "Handle", "{0}") + ")" %>'>Your Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not do this:

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="idTracking" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%#  Eval("Handle", "javascript:SendPath(\'{0}\')") %>' Text="Test" />
```

Comment: This doesn't put the quote out to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to escape any single quotes in the string you're putting into the {0} spot, too. My suggestion would be to use an HTML anchor tag rather than an asp:HyperLink control like such:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn ...>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="javascript:SendPath('<%#Container.DataItem("Handle").ToString.Replace("'", "\'") %>');">Test</a>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "SendPath(\"" + Eval( "Handle", "{0}") + "\")" %>'
```

Working Example:

**Note :** `\"` is written `"` in the Tag.

**Output**

```
NavigateUrl='SendPath("123")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to a standard html anchor tag will generally do the trick. However, if you must use an asp control maybe because of other dependencies, \x0027 will not interfere with the asp syntax.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "return confirm(\x0027Delete " + Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") + "?\x0027)" %>' Text="Delete" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure this out myself.  Here is what did that appears to work:

```
onmouseup=<% String.Format("alert('{0}')",Eval("Code"))  %>
```

**Note** the missing single quotes at the beginning.  Otherwise, the ASP.NET parser will choke on the single quote that follows the single quote after the = sign.  The HTML syntax checker underlines the text in green and says "Attribute Values Must Be Enclosed In Quotes" but it works out in the generated html.